# Workaround for menu button for newer devices

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am new to Android app development and I recently published my first app. My app uses the menu key to display 2-3 functionalities. But there are HTC Evo 4G users who sent me e-mails complaining that they cant use that because their device doesnt have a physical menu key. Now how do I implement a solution the best possible way? The app supports devices android 2.2+ How do I add a action bar without breaking my app? I was wondering if I should add a action bar for all android versions or only for 4.0 and above? What would be easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My app uses the menu key to display 2-3 functionalities.

It should be doing so by using the standard options menu system.

> Now how do I implement a solution the best possible way?

Add `android:targetSdkVersion="11"` (or higher) to your `<uses-sdk>` element in your manifest. Your title bar will be automatically converted to an action bar on API Level 11+ devices, and your options menu will appear as the overflow menu in the action bar.

> How do I add a action bar without breaking my app?

See above.

> I was wondering if I should add a action bar for all android versions

You can certainly do this, using libraries like [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, Thanks for your reply.
My app manifest already contains android:targetSdkVersion="15". So I guess thats not a problem. Now I had disabled the title bar for the activity with android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" inside the activity tag. So I removed that so that the title bar would show.  I am testing on a LG optimus one running ICS Oxygen. But the action options doesnt show in the title bar.

Comment: @Shanky: I have no idea what "ICS Oxygen" is. If the LG Optimus One has an off-screen MENU button, that is used to display the overflow menu. The overflow menu will only appear on devices (or emulators) that do not have an off-screen MENU button.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying that. Will test it on a emulator without a dedicated physical menu button.
Btw, Oxygen is one of the popular custom ROMs for android. The one I have on my phone is based on AOSP ICS 4.0.
Thanks again buddy :) I took the time to check out your website, I appreciate the work you do with your books. Cheers